# Where can I find service manuals for old (and new) lenses?

Tags: lens, repair, old-lenses

Besides Google, where can I find service manuals for old (and new) lenses?

Answer (score 2):

You can find lens service manuals on the following sites:

- [Camera Manual Library](http://OrphanCameras.com) ([butkus.org](https://www.butkus.org/chinon/) / [butkus.us](https://www.butkus.us/))
- [Boggy's Web Site](http://boggys.co.uk) – Kiron, Vivitar, Panagor

Comment: These are almost always the top results when using google to search for "*camera model x* manual."

Comment: Top results I usually get in searches are usually shopping sites and other useless pages.